# Launchers and features analysis

Tags: stock-android, launcher, nova-launcher, moto-x4

I am using stock moto launcher on my device. And, the night drain is about 6%. So, I decided to use Nova launcher. Installed Nova launcher, and after that night drain is reduced to 3%. I need to know more about launchers.

1. Launcher's ram usage: Do both launcher's run same protocol/processes (eg: notification dots like processes).
2. Device running in Nova launcher, and started some apps. Then, I switched launcher to stock(uninstalled nova). Those, apps still remained in RAM. Why the apps not get reset while switching/ not removed from RAM.
3. Some widget features got reduced. For example, google widget. It always contain text "Say Ok Google" in stock launcher. But, it is not available in Nova or pixel launcher. Why?

Comment: About 2. Why do you assume the apps launched from launcher should get stopped when launchers are switched? A launcher doesn't manage memory or processes. It is just a user-friendly interface to have all the apps listed to user to be interacted with. Those apps would stop when a user herself or through an app explicitly stops them or system decides to do so when in shortage of memory or when restarted.

Comment: When an app is removed from recents or force close through settings app info, what will happen it will get removed from Ram. Launchers are also applications. I have uninstalled second launcher and then it switched to stock launcher.

Comment: Any responses for question 1 and 3?